# haml_tag outputs directly to the Haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

What am I doing wrong with this helper for my HAML template?

```
  def display_event(event)
    event = MultiJson.decode(event)
    markup_class = get_markup_class(event)
    haml_tag :li, :class => markup_class do
      haml_tag :b, "Foo"
      haml_tag :i, "Bar"
    end
  end
```

This is the error:

```
haml_tag outputs directly to the Haml template.
Disregard its return value and use the - operator,
or use capture_haml to get the value as a String.
```

The template is calling display_event like this:

```
 - @events.each do |event|
     = display_event(event)
```

If I was using regular markup it would expand to the following

```
%li.fooclass
   %b Foo
   %i Bar
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clue’s in the error message:

```
Disregard its return value and use the - operator,
or use capture_haml to get the value as a String.
```

From the docs for [`haml_tag`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method):

> `haml_tag` outputs directly to the buffer; its return value should not be used. If you need to get the results as a string, use `#capture_haml`.

To fix it, either change your Haml to:

```
- @events.each do |event|
  - display_event(event)
```

(i.e. use the `-` operator instead of `=`), or change the method to use [`capture_haml`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method):

```
def display_event()
  event = MultiJson.decode(event)
  markup_class = get_markup_class(event)
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :li, :class => markup_class do
      haml_tag :b, "Foo"
      haml_tag :i, "Bar"
    end
  end
end
```

This will make the method return a string, which you can then display with `=` in your Haml.

Note you need to make *only one* of these changes, if you make both they will cancel each other out and you’ll get nothing displayed.